# Is Brahma Kumaris considered as a part of Hinduism?

Tags: culture

I was wondering whether they are part of Hinduism or work as a separate organisation.

Comment: Very first statement in that question says "Is Brahmakumaris Hindu organization?" So, already covered in the question.